# Is the Gluon JavaFX-SDK a JDK like thing

Tags: java, javafx, sdk, gluon

does the JFX-SDK also include the java and javac binarys? im asking since in netbeans the Build native executable option is grayed out. If yes, do i have to move it to the Java Virtual Machines Folder on my mac?

i put it in my system path but it still doesnt work

Comment: See [_Getting Started with JavaFX_](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) in the [tag:javafx] tag [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info); I keep mine in `/Users/Shared`.